# Convert List<T> to HashTable

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, hashtable, extension-methods

I have a list:

```
public class tmp
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public string LName;
    public decimal Index;
}

List<tmp> lst = GetSomeData();
```

I want to convert this list to HashTable, and I want to specify `Key` and `Value` in Extension Method Argument. For example I may want to `Key=Id` and `Value=Index` or `Key = Id + Index` and `Value = Name + LName`. How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14496667/922198

Comment: Are you using a HashTable for legacy reasons (e.g. using some third party or old code)? If not, use a Dictionary<TKey, TValue> instead, as other commenters have noted.

Comment: @AppDeveloper That's definitely the first time I've seen someone link their answer in the question's comments.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `ToDictionary` method:

```
var dic1 = list.ToDictionary(item => item.Id, 
                             item => item.Name);

var dic2 = list.ToDictionary(item => item.Id + item.Index, 
                             item => item.Name + item.LName);
```

You don't need to use `Hashtable` which comes from .NET 1.1, `Dictionary` is more type-safe.

Answer (score 6):

In C# 4.0 you can use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`:

```
var dict = lst.ToDictionary(x => x.Id + x.Index, x => x.Name + x.LName);
```

But if you really want a `Hashtable`, pass that dictionary as a parameter in `HashTable` constructor...

```
var hashTable = new Hashtable(dict);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary.aspx) extension method and pass the resulting Dictionary to the [`Hashtable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) constructor:

```
var result = new Hashtable(lst.ToDictionary(e=>e.Id, e=>e.Index));
```

Comment: This works nicely, BUT obviously it will make an extra copy of the data for the dictionary - and with large data sets this could be a problem. Fortunately, the Hashtable constructor that takes an IDictionary is only an O(N) operation - but even that can be avoided if you populate the Hashtable directly. As ever, if speed is an issue, use a Stopwatch to time things to see if the differences are significant.

Answer (score 1):

Finally the NON-Linq Way

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        List<tmp> lst = new List<tmp>();
        Dictionary<decimal, string> myDict = new Dictionary<decimal, string>();
        foreach (tmp temp in lst)
        {
            myDict.Add(temp.Id + temp.Index, string.Format("{0}{1}", temp.Name, temp.LName));
        }
        Hashtable table = new Hashtable(myDict);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As an extension method, converting `List<tmp>` to `Hashtable`;

```
public static class tmpExtensions
    {
    public static System.Collections.Hashtable ToHashTable(this List<tmp> t, bool option)
    {
        if (t.Count < 1)
            return null;

        System.Collections.Hashtable hashTable = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
        if (option)
        {
            t.ForEach(q => hashTable.Add(q.Id + q.Index,q.Name+q.LName));
        }
        else
        {
            t.ForEach(q => hashTable.Add(q.Id,q.Index));
        }
        return hashTable;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to convert the list to generic Dictionary, which is far better than raw HashTable:

```
List<tmp> list = GetSomeData();
var dictionary = list.ToDictionary(entity => entity.Id);
```

Answer (score -1):

using ForEach.

```
        List<tmp> lst = GetSomeData();
        Hashtable myHashTable = new Hashtable();
        lst.ForEach((item) => myHashTable.Add(item.Id + item.Index, item.Name + item.LName));
```

Comment: Can you give a reason why it is not useful?

Comment: You can remove all items from the list, removing them one by one. you can also just call Clear. Can you see the similarity? The best piece of code is the one you haven't written.

Comment: adding and removing are entirely different. but have you scene here that we don't need dictionary which is intermediate structure. If we use dictionary, we are adding the items two times once in dictionary and second in hashtable. Don't you think that will hit performance if data is quite high.